# Issues with Wikimedia API search function

Tags: php, xml, search, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm working on a wiki search engine based on wikimedia.

Actually, here is my query :

```
/external/wikiPublic/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=".$search."&srprop=snippet&format=xml
```

It works well but the results are terribles.
For example, it returns redirections like this :

```
<p ns="0" title="Imprimantes" snippet="#REDIRECTION [[<span class='searchmatch'>Imprimantes</span> Enseignement]] "/>
```

It tried to add the parameter &redirects=0 to the URL but it doesn't work and it still shows this kind of results.
It also put wikimedia syntax in the snippet, as you can see. It is sometimes awful, like this one :

```
<p ns="0" title="Wifi" snippet="== Le <span class='searchmatch'>Wifi</span> ici == [[Fichier:Wi-Fi_Logo.png|right|250px|Logo <span class='searchmatch'>Wifi</span>]] "/>
```

I also tried to change the snippet to sectionsnippet but it doesn't work, it returns nothing in the sectionsnippet XML attribute

So, do you know how I could resolve these issues?

- Prevent redirections in search results
- Remove wikimedia syntax or returning "plain text" or only the matching selection... I don't know which one is the best
- Show results for partial terms;  like "imprimante" returning pages containing "imprimantes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippets returned by [MediaWiki search API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aSearch) are generated by the search backend MediaWiki is [configured](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgSearchType) to use.

By default, this is the built-in database search, which indeed returns unparsed snippets.  To get nicer parsed snippets, you need to install a custom [search extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category%3aSearch_extensions), such as the Lucene-based [MWSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMWSearch) used by Wikipedia and other Wikimedia wikis.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a simple `file_get_contents` call?

```
$phrase = 'World War';

$search = str_replace( ' ', '+', $phrase );
$search_string = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?go=Go&search=' . $search;
$result = file_get_contents( $search_string );

echo $result;
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: What did not work exactly? What error did you get? Was the result not as you planned to be?

Comment: I have the same result, with redirections and wikimedia syntax : "<?xml version="1.0"?><api><query><search><p ns="0" title="Wifi" snippet="== Le &lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Wifi&lt;/span&gt; à l&#039;Ici==&#10;[[Fichier:Wi-Fi_Logo.png|right|250px|Logo &lt;span class=&#039;searchmatch&#039;&gt;Wifi&lt;/span&gt;]]&#10;" /></search></query></api>

Comment: No, I used my own URL (/external/wikiPublic/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=".$search."&srprop=snippet&format=xml) with file_get_contents. I can remove format=XML, but I'll have an already styled HTML code (with tags like <span color="blue"></span>) containing also the wikimedia syntax. :(